# com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Authenticate

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I want to send otp to user's phone number with Twillio and I am getting this error.

```
com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Authenticate
```

I wrote the logic for generating OTP, I just want to be able to send the OTP as message, and allow user enter the OTP for verification in our system.Our trial twilio account was last accessed last year, and I am trying to make the sending sms with twilio work. I logged in to the account, and twilio kept sending me to verify phone number. I am not sure of the phone number to use to verify, so I used a couple of phone numbers including the one used to set up the account but was getting this error.

```
Sorry this number has been verified on too many accounts
```

I decided to use our last used auth token, twilio sid and twilio phone number, and that was giving the Authenticate error.

This is what the send message method looks like.

```
@Override
public String sendSMS(String phoneNumber) {
    try {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Message message = Message.creator(
                        new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER),
                        new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(phoneNumber),
                        "Your One Time Password is: " + otpService.createOtpForPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)).create();

        logger.info("OTP message sent. SID: {}", message.getSid());
        return "OTP Sent, Please check your Phone";
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        logger.error("Error sending OTP message: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        System.out.println("Twilio API Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error sending OTP";
    }
}
```